# Is it possible to use global Synchronization context shared across the whole application?

Tags: async-await, vsto, outlook-addin, synchronizationcontext

I work with Outlook add-in app. It looks like Outlook objects do not have Synchronization context and await does not return the calling thread after completion. I wonder if it is possible to create a new global Synchronization context and use it for all await commands in the add-in app? If yes, how can I do this? Should I set it as Execution context property before await call? Or, there is a better solution for that?

Thank you.

Comment: try ` SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new System.Windows.Forms.WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext()); ` before calling Task.Factory.StartNew and end with `, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Outlook object model uses a single-threaded apartment model and doesn't provide any synchronization contexts out of the box. Moreover, the `SynchronizationContext` class belongs to the BCL from .net framework, not Outlook.

> I wonder if it is possible to create a new global Synchronization context and use it for all await commands in the add-in app?

Yes, if the thread doesn't have does not have its own `SynchronizationContext` instance associated with it. The running thread can be associated with a synchronization context by calling the static [SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.setsynchronizationcontext(v=vs.110).aspx) method. Later you can get the current context of the running thread using the `SynchronizationContext.Current` property.

> If yes, how can I do this? Should I set it as Execution context property before await call?

You can do that once if there is no synchronization context associated with the current thread (main). Typically Windows Forms will install an instance of the  `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext` on the thread on which the first form is created. (This thread is commonly called "the UI thread".) This synchronization context invokes the delegates passed to it on exactly that thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Namespace.SyncObjects` collection and `SyncObject.SyncStart` / `SyncEnd` events.

Comment: A synchronization context is not related to Outlook's sync objects in any way. The `SynchronizationContext` class provides the basic functionality for propagating a synchronization context in various synchronization models.

Comment: The purpose of the synchronization model implemented by this class is to allow the internal asynchronous/synchronous operations of the common language runtime to behave properly with different synchronization models. This model also simplifies some of the requirements that managed applications have had to follow in order to work correctly under different synchronization environments.